# I'm not able to communicate with Kibana server

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana, kql

I'm getting this error ***kibana server is not ready yet*** can anyone help.

Comment: Based on the information in the post, the only thing I can tell you is the kibana server isn't ready yet. I could help more if you had code and the full stacktrace.

Comment: Actually i'm very new to elasticsearch.  So just downloaded the elasticsearch and kibana. i want to start kibana server for doing some experiments. I'm getting that error.

Comment: Hi,
Usually it can take time for Kibana to start depend on your server, but not 10 minutes. It also mean that kibana is busy but didn't crash yet.
So if you can post the content of your logs, depends on how you install it.

Another alternative is using docker and follow the installation guide from the doc.

Comment: Restart the Kibana server

Answer (score 1):

Just stop and start your kibana service.

```
sudo systemctl stop kibana.service

sudo systemctl start kibana.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart the Kibana By using following cmnds

```
sudo service kibana stop
sudo service kibana start
```